# I forgot redirection operator '>' and my terminal became unresponsive

Tags: terminal, centos-7

My terminal is becoming unresponsive  after I typed below incorrect command.I am using putty Release 0.70 to ssh to Centos7. Why is the terminal unresponsive ?

```
 $ yes "abc" /dev/null &
```

I know I forgot redirection operator '>' but I don't understand why is the terminal not responding to ^C or ^Z ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process runs in background. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> have no effect on it.

Try typing `fg` <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. `fg` brings the process to the foreground.

You do not see the effect of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in your terminal because it scrolls too fast.

Comment: You beat me to it. The alternative way to recover is typing `kill %`.

Comment: That's three more keys combinations to hit ! ;-) .

Comment: That explains it. so the  argument(s)  "abc" /dev/null is treated as a single argument to the yes cmd.

Comment: thx @le_top and @Kamil Maciorowski! That explains it. so the  argument(s)  "abc" /dev/null is treated as a single argument to the `yes` cmd.  But when I tried   typing `fg` Enter and then Ctrl+C it has no effect.

Comment: @RaviKumar Maybe you had typed some characters before, so your command became e.g. `abc11fg`. Hit Ctrl+C to clear the command line and try again. Also note the solution requires your `yes` to be the current job. It is for sure if it's the only job; but if there's another job that *used to be* in the foreground, [this may be the current job](https://superuser.com/a/1254649/432690). If there's no other `yes` process you want to keep then try `killall yes`, this does not depend on jobs.

Comment: Once again thanks for the explanation @kamil-maciorowski! I realized my mistake. I forgot to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after {fg} before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kdb>c</kbd>