# The "+" and "-" signs next to the job number

Tags: command-line, bash

The bash man page says

> In  output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the
>          jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a +, and the pre‐
>          vious  job  with  a -.  A single % (with no accompanying job specifica‐
>          tion) also refers to the current job.

In my bellow series of commands, after *yes 2 > /dev/null &* , I expected job [2] to be the current job not job[1].

Also at the end of the command *yes 3 > /dev/null &* I was expecting the jobs command output to be like this:

[1]  Stopped
[2]- Running
[3]+ Running

what am I missing ?

```
$ yes 1 > /dev/null
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 yes 1 > /dev/null
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 yes 1 > /dev/null
$ yes 2 > /dev/null &
[2] 3082
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 yes 1 > /dev/null
[2]-  Running                 yes 2 > /dev/null &
$ yes 3 > /dev/null &
[3] 3116
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 yes 1 > /dev/null
[2]   Running                 yes 2 > /dev/null &
[3]-  Running                 yes 3 > /dev/null &
```

Comment: it appears the foreground job is always the most current job even if it is paused. So the foreground job, job [1] in my example above will always be indicated by the '+' sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the same man page:

> […] the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or started in the background.

It's somewhat ambiguous. You may understand it as:

1. Take all "jobs stopped while they was in the foreground or started in the background"…
2. …then choose "the last".

But it's **rather**:

1. Take "the last job stopped while it was in the foreground";
2. but in case there's no such job, take "the last job started in the background".

Comment: thanks! Looks like I understood finally.   I started yes 1 in foreground and then paused.  Then started two more foreground jobs and paused same way. Then I started three more  background jobs. Foreground job # 3 is the most current and foreground job # 2 is the previous.